# AnalyserNode's getFloatFrequencyData vs getFloatTimeDomainData

Tags: audio-recording, web-audio-api

So I think I understand `getFloatFrequencyData` pretty well. If `getFloatFrequencyData` returns an array of 1024 values, each value represents the volume of a frequency bin/range. In the case of 1024 values at a sample rate of 44.1, each value would represent the volume of a frequency range of about 20 hertz.

Now what about `getFloatTimeDomainData`? Let's say I have 2048 values, what does each value represent?

Not the same as [understanding getByteTimeDomainData and getByteFrequencyData in web audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083349/understanding-getbytetimedomaindata-and-getbytefrequencydata-in-web-audio). Or at least, this question's answer doesn't answer mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Float32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array) obtained using `getFloatTimeDomainData` will contain an array of sample values, each value defining the *amplitude* at the sampled location, usually in the domain of `[-1, 1]`. Sample locations are uniquely distributed, the obtained data is essentially the equivalent of raw [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation).

For a sine wave, it would yield gradually changing continuous values among the following approximation curve:

```
0 ... 0.7 ... 1.0 ... 0.7 ... 0 ... -0.7 ... -1.0 ... -0.7 ... 0 ...
```

Think of it as a series of subsequent values that together define the *shape* of the audio wave; if you were to visualize the obtained values on, say, a canvas, using the sample values as `y` coordinates (amplitude) and a subsequently increasing value for `x` coordinates (time), you would get an [oscilloscope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API#Creating_a_waveformoscilloscope), such as:

[image: sine wave]

Note how this sine waveform correlates with the example values above. Here are some example operations you can do on this data to get a better understanding:

- If you were to multiply each value by 2, you would amplify the volume by 100% (double volume)
- If you were to replace every value with 0, you would get silence
- If you were to skip every second value, you would get a 100% pitched up audio (double playback speed)

Answer (score 3):

getFloatTimeDomainData returns a sample of the PCM data from the audio stream - i.e. the raw audio data.

Comment: Precisely, what does each value represent? A frequency data value represents the volume of a frequency range. A time domain data represents x of y?